# Problem extracting data from file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a large data file and want to split it into smaller files based on values in column 1.
For example column 1 has numbers from 1 to 10 ten times to make 100 rows and I want all lines with numbers '1' or '2' or '3' etc in their own file (preferably without sorting). 
Also I dont want to run the command 10 times so would like for it to be in a loop.

My files look like this:

- `text.txt`

  [image]
- `ID.txt`

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ```

The command I tried:

```
cat ID.txt | while read line; do awk '$1 == ${line}' test.txt >$line.txt;done
```

So to summarize I want it to read the value from the ID.txt file e.g '1' and then extract all rows with '1' in the first line and put it in a file called 1.txt, then it iterates to 2 then 3 then 4 etc.

But somehow the '$1 == ${line}' part I think is not working

Comment: Please include an example of your actual file. Not a screenshot of it, the text itself. You can use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to make it look like code.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `-v` option to `awk`:

```
   -v var=val
   --assign var=val
          Assign the value val to the variable var,  before  execution  of
          the  program  begins.  Such variable values are available to the
          BEGIN rule of an AWK program.
```

Something like this:

```
cat ID.txt | 
    while read line; do awk -vline="$line" '$1 == l' test.txt >"$line".txt;done
```

Which would be better expressed as (avoiding the useless use of cat):

```
while read line; do 
    awk -vline="$line" '$1 == l' test.txt >"$line".txt;
done < ID.txt
```

However, this is very slow and inefficient. You are running the `awk` command on the entire `test.txt` for each line of `ID.txt`. Why not just read `ID.txt` in `awk` itself and print the matching lines:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} ($1 in a){print >> $1".txt"}' ID.txt test.txt
```

The above saves the 1st field of `ID.txt` in the array `a`. `NR` and `FNR` are special `awk` variables meaning "the current line of the input stream" and "the current line of the current file". The two will only be equal to each other when the first file is being read. Therefore, `NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}` will only be run on the lines of the first file. The second part will not be executed because the `next` tells `awk` to skip to the next line.

The second part, checks if the current line's 1st field (remember, this is only run on the second file) exists in the array `a` (which means it was in `ID.txt`) and, if it does, prints the line into a file called "field1.txt"